# Mixed Content blocked when connecting to http-bind from angular js web client

Tags: ejabberd, strophe, mixed-content

I have an jabbed installation and use http-bind to connect my angular.js + strophe web client. I added ssl/tls encryption to the web app and now chrome does not connect allow the BOSH connection giving a Mixed content error and blocks it. It works fine on safari. I am connecting using 'http://example.com:5280/http-bind'. I also see that chrome allows some other mixed content (files I have hosted on google blob store) but blocks the Strophe bosh connection. Any ideas?

Comment: you cannot load files with http on https request. this is mixed content loading. and you can do it vice-versa.

Comment: Thanks @JSantosh, but my issue is a broader one. I am trying to setup up my ejabberd web chat application (using angular and strophe) over https and am having issues connecting to http-bind. My issue is 'how do I connect to http://example.com:5280/http-bind over https on chrome?